# Dialog close on .k-overlay click

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I have not seen a built in way to have the dialog close when you click on the .k-overlay div or hit the escape key. This has been a fairly standard way for users to close dialog in the past and I just wanted to make sure that I'm not missing something.

Is there a built in way (not accessing the ElementRef and hooking up click events) to close the dialog from escape and backdrop click?

If not I can wrap the kendo dialog in a component to extend it's functionality and or make a request for a feature. Thanks.

**Update**
So if there is not a way to do this I have come up with a work around in case others run up to this issue.

First create an attribute directive for the click and escape functionality:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, Renderer2, AfterViewInit,  } from "@angular/core";
import { DialogComponent } from "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog";

@Directive({
  selector: "[kendoDialogExtension]"
})
export class AsiKendoDialogExtensionsDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() kendoDialogExtension: DialogComponent;
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const element = this.el.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
    this.renderer.listen(element, "click", () => {
      this.kendoDialogExtension.close.emit();
    })
  }

  @HostListener("document:keydown", ["$event"])
  handelKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.keyCode === 27 && this.kendoDialogExtension) {
      this.kendoDialogExtension.close.emit();
    }
  }
}
```

Then Create a wrapper component that looks something like this:

```
   <div [kendoDialogExtension]="kendoDialog" *ngIf="opened">
      <kendo-dialog #kendoDialog [title]="title" (close)="closed.emit($event)">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
      </kendo-dialog>
    </div>
```